# Show other column value if the value of the column is NULL or blank

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display value of other column if the value of my column is NULL or blank. Below is my table.

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE(ID INT, suser VARCHAR(10), sgroup VARCHAR(10), sregion VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO  @Tab VALUES(1,'Test',NULL,NULL),(2,'','Group',NULL),(3,NULL,NULL,'Region'),(4,NULL,NULL,NULL)

SELECT * from @Tab
```

My Query:

```
SELECT ID 
,Case WHEN suser IS NULL OR suser = ''
            THEN sgroup
      WHEN sgroup IS NULL OR sgroup = ''
            THEN sregion
     ELSE NULL
     END AS col 
            from @Tab
```

I want oupput as:-

```
DECLARE @Tab1 TABLE(ID INT, col VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO  @Tab1 VALUES(1,'Test'),(2,'Group'),(3,'Region'),(4,NULL)
SELECT * from @Tab1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  COALESCE function it will return 1st non null value

```
 SELECT ID ,COALESCE(suser , sgroup, sregion)     
          col 
       from @Tab
```

Comment: This won't handle the blank strings (`''`).

Comment: Surprised this was marked as the correct answer, considering that this won't provide the expected result. For ID 2, the return value is `''`. The OP's expected result clearly states they expect the value `'Group'`. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e4a68/1)

Answer (score 3):

Blank and `NULL` are not the same. If you want to treat `''` and `NULL` as the same value, one method would be to use `NULLIF`:

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(YourFirstColumn,''),YourOtherColumn)
```

Ideally, however, if either could be stored in your data but they should be treated as the same, don't allow one of them. Personally, I would update all the values of the column to `NULL` where they have a value of `''` and then add a constraint that doesn't allow the value `''`. Something like:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = NULL
WHERE YourColumn = '';

ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT YourColumn_NotBlank CHECK (YourColumn IS NULL OR YourColumn <> '');
```

Comment: your constraint will accept nulls. I think you meant **YourColumn IS NOT NULL AND YourColumn <> ''**

Comment: @t-clausen.dk no, that was exactly what i wanted. *"if either could be stored in your data but they should be treated as the same, **don't allow one of them**"*. So, in my example, I am permitting `NULL`, but not a blank string `''`. The OP clearly needs one at least, as they have both `NULL` and `''` values, so not allowing both would likely introduce a breaking change. if, however, I were to want to stop `NULL`, then changing the definition of the column would be better. I.e. `ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn varchar(x) NOT NULL;` *(Where x is the current length)*